# Microsoft C/C++ 7.0 Compiler for DOS or OpenWatcom equivalent

Tags: dos

I'm working through some old material that includes a lot of DOS32 code that was compiled with MS C/C++ 7.0. I could compile most of it setting up an OpenWatcom project but I'm struggling with some inline assembly and other stuff. All the codes were compiled with `"CL -C -AM -G2 -Gs -Zi -W4 FILENAME.C"`. I was looking for this old compiler but haven't found it. OpenWatcom installed with a CL clone but the parameters don't work with that. Best thing I dould do is getting MS 7.0 Compiler and run it via DosBox I think... Any suggestions? I'd appreciate them ;) thanks!

Comment: You could try Visual C++ 1.52, which IIRC was [the last available for DOS](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/145669) and I think an extension of the old non-Visual compiler. It is available from [MSDN subscriber downloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads) if you have access, and a few less-legal looking downloads if you search for it. (But if you have a license for any more recent Visual Studio you will be licensed to use it legally, as they include down-version rights last I checked.) If you specifically need 7 though you might be out-of-luck.